# Prevent click handler firing on child

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway to stop the parent click event going off when a specific child element is touched.

For example in this example I want to log `outer` which clicking blue and `inner` when clicking red.

How do I stop the outer event firing on inner div?

```js
$("#outer").click(function(){
  console.log("outer");                 
});

//tried these but doesnt do anything
$("#inner").off();
$("#inner").unbind();

$("#inner").click(function(e){
  console.log("inner");                 
});
```

```css
#outer{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
}
#inner{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `stopPropagation` to prevent the event from bubbling up and triggering the listener on `#outer`:

```js
$("#outer").click(function(){
  console.log("outer");                 
});
$("#inner").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log("inner");                 
});
```

```css
#outer{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
}
#inner{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will accept in 10 mins when timer runs out